# how to add a new value on the previous value of a column in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make an ATM Simulator. When I want to add some money in my account which is registered in SQL Server, I don't know how to add a value over the old value.
My SQL Table is like this:

**Name**  |  **Surname** |    **Pin** |   **Money**

When i want to add Money from textBox in the Money column I don't know how.

Code:

```
        con.Open();
        string connString = "";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Useri where Pin='" + textBox1_Pin.Text + "' ";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        double balanciFillestar = Convert.ToDouble(reader[3]);
        double balanciRi = balanciFillestar + double.Parse(textBox_shuma.Text);
        cmd.CommandText = "update Useri set Shuma =" + balanciRi + "";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The most immediate need would be to filter the `update` statement, so instead of this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Useri set Shuma =" + balanciRi + "";
```

you really need this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Useri SET Shuma = @Shuma WHERE Pin = @Pin";
```

But, before you can do that we really need to refactor it all.

```
var selectSql = "SELECT Shuma FROM Useri WHERE Pin = @Pin";
var updateSql = "UPDATE Useri SET Shuma = @Shuma WHERE Pin = @Pin";

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    c.Open();

    double balanciFillestar;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", textBox1_Pin.Text);

        balanciFillestar = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    double balanciRi = balanciFillestar + double.Parse(textBox_shuma.Text);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shuma", balanciRi);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", textBox1_Pin.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

There are a number of things I'm doing here that you'll want to learn from:

1. The SQL statements are parameterized.
2. The `SqlConnection` *is not shared.*
3. The ADO.NET objects are wrapped in a `using` statement.
4. A `SqlDataReader` isn't used to get a single value from a single row.

All of these things, with the exception of #4, are equally important.

Point #1 ensures that you're protecting yourself from SQL Injection attacks.

Point #2 is quite simply the only viable way to use the class. It's meant to be constructed, opened, used, and disposed.

Point #3 ensures that the `Dispose` method is called on all of the objects. This is extremely important with these classes because they implement `IDisposable`. They do because they handle unmanaged resources (i.e. a connection to a SQL server).

Point #4 is really just an optimization. Data readers are meant for reading very large data sets, one row at a time, to gain performance and resource management. Likewise the data reader is actually left open until it is closed or disposed. Generally speaking there are almost always better API's to use than a data reader unless using it for their express purpose.

Comment: (cString) dows not exist in the current context

Comment: @Arbnor, no I wouldn't expect it to. It's your connection string. Further, again, *do not share* the connection you were clearly sharing before.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I did without using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
Thank you very much.

Comment: I have another request for you.
Can you help me how can datagridview refresh automatically when I add Deposit? Because I must click in my View Details buton to refresh the datagrid.
Thank you

Comment: @Arbnor, it would be best for you to collect all the relevant code and post a new question. There is a great wealth of folks here that can help you pretty quickly.

Comment: I collected that. I hope you will help me now.

Comment: @Arbnor, did you ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613878/atm-simulator-log-in-deposit-and-others-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Arbnor, that question is going to get closed quickly. You need to put some real effort into the question. Describe what's wrong and what needs fixed, and only include the relevant code, not all of it.

Comment: All of this code is OK, but I want to refresh automatically datagridview details when I give values in textbox and when I click Deposit button, because to refresh the datagridview details I must to click again in the View Details Buton

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable against SQL injection. Please consider this and use parameterized query.

```
string ps= "update Useri set Shuma = Shuma + @shuma WHERE Pin= @pin";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ps, c);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shuma", textBox_shuma.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", textBox1_Pin.Text);
```

Comment: `PreparedStatement` is a Java API isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I have just waken up (:. Sorry for that.